# ReDim Preserve stopped working in Excel VBA code

Tags: excel, dynamic-arrays, vba

I have an Excel VBA macro that colleagues have been using without issues for a couple of years now, and suddenly as of December 1st, everyone is getting a "Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range" error. The code below summarizes the gist of the issue:

```
Dim before As Long
Dim after As Long
Dim baseInd As Variant
baseInd = Array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
before = LBound(baseInd)
ReDim Preserve baseInd(1 To 18)
after = LBound(baseInd)
```

Even after specifying that array baseInd should start at index 1, it still starts at 0 (here variable after has value 0, as does variable before), which eventually causes the rest of my code to crash. I have learned recently of the Option Base 1 instruction, but I cannot use it here, as this would cause issues with other arrays.

Again this used to work perfectly before and I do not have the slightest clue why all of a sudden (December 1st 2014) I'm getting this error. Anyone has an idea?

Thanks!

Comment: What type of variable is "GL_LABL_ORI"

Comment: GL_LABL_ORI is a constant of type Long. The value is 18.

Comment: any reason why not just go with 0 through 17?

Comment: @PJ Rosenburg No good reason other than the fact that this is old code and multiple arrays have been defined the same way. I'm just trying to avoid rework. But if I don't find the solution, I'll just have to recode with indices starting from 0.

Comment: I could reproduce the error under certain conditions and was able to solve it by adding `Dim baseInd` before you create the array.  Don't add the type after it.  Here is a [msdn link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264145%28v=office.15%29.aspx) with a little more info about Explicit declaration.

Comment: @PortlandRunner Thanks for your comment. In the sample code I posted above I forgot to include the declaration of the baseInd variable, but it was there in my code (I always use Option Explicit). The fact that you could reproduce the error under certain conditions is very interesting. Under what circumstances does that happen for you?

Comment: @PortlandRunner Thanks for the tip. I removed the  `As Variant`, but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: Okay, one more try.  If I define the variable with `()` like this: `Dim baseInd()` or `Dim baseInd() as Variant` then I'll get the `Subscript Out of Range` error and the debugger will highlight the `Redim` line.  Removing the `()` will solve the error.  But now that you've posted your `Dim` statement I can see that shouldn't be the case unless you have another array defined this way somewhere in your code.

Comment: @PortlandRunner Again thank you for trying to help me. Much appreciated. I also get the `Subscript Out of Range` error when I declare `Dim baseInd()`. We are in agreement there. In my particular case I did not use the parentheses and I do not get an error per se. My issue is that even after the `ReDim Preserve baseInd(1 To 18)` statement, where I specify that the index should start at 1, variable `after` is still 0, which eventually causes code later on to crash. Back when I originally wrote the code, this worked as expected, but not anymore. What is the value of `after` for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what we are seeing in my company and after copious research, it seems that the MS KB3003057 security patch recently issued has broken the ReDim Preserve function.  Please see [this forum](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?780891-PRB-Wrong-ReDim-Preserve-caused-by-a-bug-in-OLE-automation-after-recent-updates) for more details on how others are seeing the same issue.

Comment: Thanks so much for the thread. This is exactly the issue I am having. I was starting to think I was crazy! May I ask how your company is dealing with this issue? In my case I would have to make numerous changes to the existing code and I would like to avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know, nothing in VBA changed on 1/12/2014 that would cause this.  Without more code, it is impossible to know what caused it in your code.

But, this highlights the danger of relying on default array lower bounds.  You should go back and specify the lower bound in all your arrays declarations.

Eg

```
Redim arr(5 to 42) As SomeType
```

Note that while you can specify the *default* lower bound using `Option Base ...` this only applies to arrays where you don't specify an explicit lower bound.

An alternative (and to my mind, inferior) way is to omit the lower bound in the Redim:

```
ReDim Preserve baseInd(GL_LABL_ORI)
```

---

Followup from updated OP

You say *Even after specifying that array baseInd should start at index 1,* but nowhere in your code do you specify a lower bound of 1.  The lower bound is in fact determined by the `Array` function.  Refer to the VBA online help for details.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I added some code to clarify the issue. I know some of my coding habits are probably sub-par, but what really puzzles me is that a simple instruction that has been working fine for over 2 years now all of a sudden stopped working for everyone at the company.